# IDLE crashes for certain buttons on Mac

Tags: python, macos, button, crash, python-idle

I am running OS X 10.9.5, and IDLE w/ Python 3.4.1.

When I press the buttons for (¨/^) or (´/`), IDLE crashes and the program closes.

This causes me to lose changes to files, as well as time. My fellow students using Mac experience the same problem.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What does (´/`) mean? is it a slash?

Comment: I'm trying to separate the "value" of the buttons.

It's the button to the left of the backspace button and the one to the left of the top part of the enter button.

If you press the buttons you get ´ and ¨, but if you hold shift you get ` and ^.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that the version of tcl/tk you are using is having a problem with your non-US national keyboard (which country?)  Un-shifted, those key produce non-ascii diacritic chars, `ord(´)==180` and `ord(¨)==168`, that are usually composed with another character.

The download page, at the bottom, directs OSX users to this [mac-tck/tk](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk) page.
That page says to install ActiveTcl 8.5.16.0 from ActiveState.  The older tcl/tk 8.5.9 from Apple has a problem with composition chars that has since been fixed

In the meanwhile, start Idle in a console window with `python3 -m idlelib` (I think `python3` is the correct name for OSX) and you should see some error messages that should verify the above. This may also solve the problem of Idle stopping.

Comment: I downloaded ActiveTcl 8.5 and installed it, but how do I get it to be used by idle?

Comment: At this point, the recommendation is for 8.5.18 instead of 8.5.16.  I don't know any more than given on the linked mac-tcl/tk page.  Or install Python 2.7.15, 3.6.7rc1, https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-367rc1/, or 3.7.1rc1, https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-371rc1/, for Mac, which now come with included tcl/tk.  Do not install 3.6.6 or 3.7.0 (both buggy).  The final 3.6.7 and 3.7.1 should be released in about a week.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem, Try British pc keyboard it works for me